# what is the easiest way to remove all entries from a select dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown and i want to clear all items from it using jquery.  i see a lot of google links about removing selected item but i want to clear ALL items from a dropdown.

what is the best way of removing all items from a select dropdown list?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**BEST way:** use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('select').empty();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zy22N/1/)**

**Note:**  Use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) when you want to remove the element **itself**, as well as everything inside it

Comment: Didn't even consider that. Definitely a better way to do it.

Comment: True. `empty()` is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#idOfDropdown option').remove();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zy22N/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('option', the_select_element).remove();
```

If you want to keep the selected:

```
$('option:not(:selected)', the_select_element).remove();
```

It's really simple in plain JS, too (thanks, @Austin France!):

```
// get the element
var sel = document.getElementById("the_select_ID");
// as long as it has options
while (sel.options.length) {
  // remove the first and repeat
  sel.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Simple JS way to do this: var options = el.options; while (options.length) options[0].remove();

Comment: It works a bit different: `while (select_element.options.length) select_element.remove(0);` but yes. Thanks for mentioning the native interface!